# how to display data in rows and columns XAML windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8

In metro style windows 8 application, how can i display the data using xaml similar to this (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59251888/img.png)image. is it possible using ListBox,ListView,GrdView.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you need to style it up so that it looks like a datagrid. (Assuming you are developing in XAML based on the tags you've assigned to this question). The trick is to make a data template that uses a Grid with columns with proper widths, alignments etc.

I've done something similar - using a ListView. This could be modified to make the backgrounds appear only for cells as opposed to rows - which I have done. Hope this helps:

[image: ListView simulating the look of a data grid / table]

XAML:

```
 <ListView 
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Margin="0,5"
      ItemsSource="{Binding HighestExpensesAlternatingList}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HighestExpensesTemplate}"
      BorderBrush="#19FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" 
      SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleListViewItemStyle}"
      IsHitTestVisible="False"/>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="HighestExpensesTemplate">
        <Grid Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0"
              Background="{Binding AlternatingIndexBrush}">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                       Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Item.DateString}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                       Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Item.Description}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                       Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Item.AmountStringCurrencyFormat}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="SimpleListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsDoubleTapEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsRightTapEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="Container"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid x:Name="Container">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually you have showed one item per row, with different attributes in different columns, i want to show 3 items per row,each item in a different column.. any ideas of can i do this ..?

Comment: I think you may be able to use a GridView with its ItemsPanel set to a WrapGrid with the property Orientation="Horizontal" and MaximumRowsOrColumns="3". Then you would style it to make it looks like seperate rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks alot Krishna, i used the WrapGrid  as you mentioned, and it worked exactly as i wanted.. 
Thanks

Comment: this is a great answer, thank you! Do you have an idea how to avoid that the listview gets grey background when you put a mouse over it? thanks

Comment: I think you may have to override the ListViewItem template and fix up the VisualStates inside. Or atleast override one or more of the default ListViewItem* brushes.