# Add Items to Columns in a WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, listview

I've been struggling for a while now to add items to 2 columns in a `ListView`. In my Windows Forms application I had a something like this:

```
// In my class library:
public void AddItems(ListView listView)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem {Text = "Some Text for Column 1"};
    item.SubItems.Add("Some Text for Column 2");

    listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I would then call this class from my `Form.cs`.

How can I do this in WPF? Preferably, I wouldn't like to use a lot of XAML.

Comment: What's wrong with XAML?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

### Solution With Less XAML and More C#

If you define the `ListView` in XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"/>
```

Then you can add columns and populate it in C#:

```
public Window()
{
    // Initialize
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Add columns
    var gridView = new GridView();
    this.listView.View = gridView;
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { 
        Header = "Id", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Id") });
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { 
        Header = "Name", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name") });

    // Populate list
    this.listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { Id = 1, Name = "David" });
}
```

*See definition of `MyItem` below.*

### Solution With More XAML and less C#

However, it's easier to define the columns in XAML (inside the `ListView` definition):

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And then just populate the list in C#:

```
public Window()
{
    // Initialize
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Populate list
    this.listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { Id = 1, Name = "David" });
}
```

*See definition of `MyItem` below.*

### `MyItem` Definition

`MyItem` is defined like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Partial solution for **UWP** / **WinRT**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828704/listview-win8-xaml-how-to-create-columns