# Can't See ListViewItem.SubItems

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem, wpf-4.0

For some reason, when I write the following code in my Visual Studio 2010 (.NET Framework 4.5):

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("item1");
item.SubItems
```

there is no such field as SubItems.

What could be the reason for that?

Regards,
Vitalii.

Comment: Are you using winforms?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, at least in `winforms`.

Look a little closer, once you add the dot the usual list of items should come up:

[image]

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("item1");
item.SubItems.Add("subitem1");
```

Note: To declare an instance you need to reference the class like this:

```
ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
```

Also note: Sometimes Intellisense stops working; I have to restart VS to bring it back to life..

If however you are targeting `WPF`, then you are right: There are **no** `SubItems` in a `WPF ListViewItem`. It is a `ContentControl`, which can contain whatever you put there, I believe. But I'm no WPF expert. A good book may be best..

> ```
>           System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl
>             System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem
>               System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem
> ```

Comment: Actually when I compile your code I get 'no constructor that takes 1 argument' and 'no Subitems'.

Comment: `Subitems` is wrong It is `SubItems`. Always watch out for the spelling! The code as posted compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ListViewItem` constructor that takes a string array, where the first element is the main item text and the other are the `SubItems` texts:

```
var myNewItem = new ListViewItem(new[]
                { 
                    "First column", 
                    "Second column", 
                    "Third column"
                });

myListItem.Items.Add(myNewItem);
```

Of course, you have to set your `ListView` Mode to `Detail` mode, and create the `Columns` collection accordingly.

EDIT: This is a WinForm tip... I dont know if it applies to WPF unfortunately.

Comment: To make it work, yes. To compile you can leave it in the default View mode. You just see no subitems when you run it..

Comment: Well I just realize the question is about intellisense that does not shows "SubItems" property, rather than invisible subitems during runtime.

Comment: Or maybe he is really targeting WPF..?

Comment: Unfortunately, both codes doesn't work in my Vusial Studio, and the problem seem to be not about Intellisense (nor spelling...). Your code gives me this: 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. Maybe that is something wrong with my Visual Studio? I tried on my friend's one and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I am using WPF. Why?

Comment: OK, not it's seems googleable. I found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865829/add-items-to-columns-in-a-wpf-listview. Is it the right way?

Comment: _Yes, I am using WPF. Why?_ Because there is a completely different control with the same name in WinForms!! Please __always__ tag your question with WPF or ASP or Winforms, where applicable ot you get wrong answers and waste out time.. BTW: The same is true for many other Controls!