# wpf - listview inside of tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, tabcontrol

I'm having difficulties to `Binding` a `ListView` inside of a `TabControl`
Bellow is my ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }
public class TabItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<abc> Content { get; set; }
}
public class abc
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

this is how I initialize it

```
InitializeComponent();
Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>()
{
    new TabItem {
        Header = "Header1",
        Content = new ObservableCollection<abc>()
        {
            new abc{ text = "content1" },
            new abc{ text = "content2" },
        }
    },
    new TabItem {
        Header = "Header2",
        Content = new ObservableCollection<abc>()
        {
            new abc{ text = "content3" },
            new abc{ text = "content4" },
        }
    }
};
tabControl1.ItemsSource = Tabs;
```

and here is how I populate and `Bind` it in the view

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl1">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- this is the header template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Width="500" Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Content}">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

but then I got an errror saying that

```
InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.
```

How can I bind a `ListView` inside a `TabControl`?
Each Tab control will have the same format of `ListView`. The Actual ListView will have more than 1 field. not only `text` field.

Where did I do it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListViewItems are created by ListView for each element in ItemsSource. To change their look you need ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Content}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

if you have more than 1 field, not only text field, define `GridView` with columns like [shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865829/add-items-to-columns-in-a-wpf-listview)

Comment: thx for the explanation. I always thought my problem was with the `Binding`. It turns out that the problem was with `ItemTemplate`. since each `ListView` would still be designed into a box, so im planing to use `Grid` inside the `DataTemplate`. thank you