# Binding to Custom List Works On A DataGrid but Not on a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Why the object class name gets listed in a bound ListView instead of the object instance's property values?

Correct amount (so DataContext is set) of rows consisting of only complete class name "MyNameSpace.MyClass" is listed without column headers with following xaml:

MyClass property getters are never called.

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="MyClassesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassesItemsSource}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Contract number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ContractNumberProperty}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StatusProperty}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

class:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public string ContractNumber;
    public int Status;

    public string ContractNumberProperty 
    {
        get { return ContractNumber; }
        set { ContractNumber = value;  }
    }

    public int StatusProperty 
    {
        get { return Status; }
        set { Status = value;  }
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
public class MyClassesViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private ItemsSource<MyClass> _myClassesItemsSource;
    public ItemsSource<MyClass> MyClassesItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _myClassesItemsSource;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ref _myClassesItemsSource, value);
        }
    }
}
```

explanation of own classes used:

```
class ItemsSource<T> implements: INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable

class ViewModel implements: INotifyPropertyChanged

method SetValue<T> raises: PropertyChanged
```

BindingSource, IEnumerable, IEnumerable,

```
public abstract class ViewModel : BindingSource
```

EDIT:

This works perfect as DataGrid:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="MyClassesDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassesItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contract number" Binding="{Binding ContractNumberProperty}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding StatusProperty}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The name of the class is the result of the ToString method. Your ListView.View isn't working.

Comment: thanx for comment! any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: ListView.ItemTemplate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828704/listview-win8-xaml-how-to-create-columns

Comment: @ Oscar:That is different than the gridview in wpf. Maybe you can look at this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection

Comment: @JeroenDop: that is about binding columns to viewmodel. i.e. not having fixed columns like I do

Comment: Have you tried setting the ItemSource in code behind instead of the binding in xaml? MyClassesListView.ItemsSource =_myClassesItemsSource;

Comment: @JeroenDop That won't help. His problem is that he needs to display the items.

Comment: yes. I get the rows (class name) in list but no column headers or item property values so itemssource binding works, what does not work is the individual item column to property bindings

Comment: @matti Did you write 'ItemsSource' yourself? I just tried your code, but I didn't have `ItemsSource` so I used `ObservableCollection` instead -- and it worked correctly.

Comment: @matti I was able to reproduce the issue by commenting out the `ListView.View` element and all its contents. Are you quite certain that the XAML in your question is precisely the exact same XAML you're looking at in the window at runtime?

Comment: ItemsSource is not written by me, but it works. I get same results with ObservableCollection

Comment: I have edited the XAML only to remove identifiable names, so no, it's not the same. Also the real class for a row contains like 30 properties.

Comment: actually the XAML is exactly same. only the ItemsSource property is different. however that binding works so effectively it's exactly the same.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I edited the question. This works perfect as DataGrid without changing ViewModel or the row class (MyClass). It would be nice to know what was wrong, but I stick to DataGrid which is by far superior (for 1st, it works).

Comment: @matti If it works, it works.